# getting weird "missing output " error when running a nextflow pipeline

Tags: nextflow

For my data analysis pipeline I am using `nextflow` (which is a workflow management system) and I gave all the required arguments in the main command but I am getting a weird error. Basically in the output section I introduce the output but the error is missing output. I have made 3 files to run the pipeline including:

1- the module containing the main code to run the tool (ASEReadCounter) and named `ASEReadCounter.nf` :

```
process ASEReadCounter {
    input:
        file vcf_file
        file bam_file
        path(genome_fasta)


    output:

        file "${vcf_file}.ASE.csv"

    script:

    """
    gatk ASEReadCounter \\
            -R ${params.genome}  \\
            -V ${params.vcf_infile}  \\
            -O ${params.vcf_infile}.txt \\
            -I ${params.bam_infile}
        """
}
```

2- the main file which is used to run the pipeline named `main.nf` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.preview.dsl=2

include ASEReadCounter from './modules/ASEReadCounter.nf'

genome_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.genome)
vcf_file_ch=Channel.fromPath(params.vcf_infile)
bam_infile_ch=Channel.fromPath(params.bam_infile)

workflow {
    count_ch=ASEReadCounter(genome_ch, vcf_file_ch, bam_infile_ch)
}
```

3- config file which is named `nextflow.config` :

```
params {
    genome = '/hpc/hg38_genome/GRCh38.p13.genome.fa'
    vcf_infile = '/hpc/test_data/test/test.vcf.gz'
    bam_infile = ‘/hpc/test_data/test/test.sorted.bam'
}

process {

    shell = ['/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail']
    withName: ASEReadCounter {
        container = 'broadinstitute/gatk:latest'
    }
}

singularity {
           enabled = true
           runOptions = '-B /hpc:/hpc -B $TMPDIR:$TMPDIR'
           autoMounts = true
           cacheDir = '/hpc/diaggen/software/singularity_cache'
}
```

here is the command I use to run the whole pipeline:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error executing process > 'ASEReadCounter (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `GRCh38.p13.genome.fa.ASE.csv` expected by process `ASEReadCounter (1)`

Command executed:

  gatk ASEReadCounter             -R /hpc/hg38_genome/GRCh38.p13.genome.fa  \
      -V /hpc/test_data/test/test.vcf.gz  \
      -O /hpc/test_data/test/test.vcf.gz.txt \
      -I /hpc/test_data/test/test.sorted.bam
```

Do you know how I can fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your ASEReadCounter process expects a file with the pattern `${vcf_file}.ASE.csv` as output, as defined at:

```
output:
file "${vcf_file}.ASE.csv"
```

I assume the line `-O ${params.vcf_infile}.txt` makes it so your `gatk ASEReadCounter` command writes its output to a file with the pattern `$params.vcf_infile}.txt`. The expected output and the actual output filenames don't match and nextflow throws an error because it doesn't want to contine since a downstream process might need the output file. You can fix it by matching the expected output and actual output patterns,

Comment: with this I get the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the `.txt` from the end of the output pattern?

Comment: if I removed ".txt" ( file ("${vcf_file}") ) then I will get this error: [01/30eff0] Cached process > ASEReadCounter (1) –

Comment: I don't see the error message in the last output you posted